# updating the dataset file in python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to update the values of `Data.csv` with the new values of `x` and `y`. How can I update this dataset?

```
import numpy as np  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
import pandas as pd  
dataset= pd.read_csv('Data.csv')  
x=dataset.iloc[: , :-1].values  
y=dataset.iloc[:, 3].values  
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer  
imputer = Imputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy='mean', axis=0)  
imputer = imputer.fit(x[ : , 1:3])  
x[:, 1:3]= imputer.transform(x[:, 1:3])
```

Comment: Writing to a file is covered well in on-line documentation and tutorials.  Where are you stuck with those resources?  Show your problem code.

Comment: As I have updated the missing data in array x, So I want the changes made in to be reflected back in Data.csv file.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html - http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Answer (score 1):

Files and in-memory data structures have no inherent tie to each other. If you've changed your data and you want to overwrite the file with the new data, just write your new data back to disk to the same filename:

```
dataset = pd.concat([x, y], axis=1)
dataset.to_csv('Data.csv')
```